How could I use NavigationSuiteScaffold in Android and Jetpack Compose after authentication process
I would like to understand how could I achieve:

Show a Login screen
When the user is logging in, I would like to show a home page with bottom navigation (4 options), but I'm using NavigationSuiteScaffold for that.

I'm a bit confused how to integrate NavigationSuiteScaffold:

Should I include as a the main Scaffold?
How could I achieve this flow?

Thanks in advance
